# Log htaccess apache access user stored in .htpasswd in a file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

I will use my *.htaccess* in order to store users crendtials with this config :

```
<FilesMatch "secret.php">
 AuthName "Member Only"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUserFile /home/realboss/.htpasswd
 require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

I have a *.htpasswd* file with these fake credentials :

```
admin:$fdslkjhdfsqklbhjndfsqbkjln
boss:$fdslkjhdfsqklbhjndfsqbkjln
staff_boss:$fdslkjhdfsqklbhjndfsqbkjln
```

I want to log user connection in a file. An example logfile that I want :

File *apache_connection.log*:

```
secret.php admin 2018-08-23 08:20:10
secret.php staff_boss 2018-08-19 11:35:41
...
```

[Apache doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/howto/auth.html) don't give a way to do that...

Comment: This might help you @jedema - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html Looking at the *Access Log* onwards parts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. So it's the %u of format log which define username in logfile ?

Comment: I see the answer of my question in this link (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43474/how-to-log-username-in-apache-logs). I'll publish an answer later to give solution. Big thanks !

Comment: Great! Glad that the link helped :) I wasn't 100% sure on the formatting hence why I just posted that link in a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: This is actually a more up-to-date version for Apache 2.4: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog